# Code only runs sometimes when input is added to if statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some code for vaulting over waist high objects in my game.

```
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        upper = GetComponentInChildren<Vaultupper>().uppertrig;
        if (upper == false && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("vaulted");
            objectpos = other.transform.position;
            objectpos.y = 0;
            objectpos.Normalize();
            objectpos = objectpos * 2;
            Player.transform.Translate(objectpos);
        }
    }
```

upper is a variable that's set to true when a trigger on the player's head is active, telling this code the object is too high to vault over. The trigger in this code is for one at the players feet, which checks if there's an object at all.
My problem is when i change the if statement to run when upper == false, it runs fine, but once i add also requiring the player to press space, it only runs 1/5 or so of the times i hit space at a vaultable obstacle. How might i get it to run consistently with having to press space?

Comment: Remove the requirement of pressing space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered replacing "GetKeyDown" with "GetKey" makes it work right.